# C# JSON.Net Serialize Dictonnary issues with decode in PHP

Tags: c#, php, json, json.net

I am looking for a way to get this

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "object1": {
      "propertie1": "value",
      "propertie2": "value"
    },
    "object2": {
      "propertie1": "value",
      "propertie2": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

C# i got an object like this

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Dictionnary<string, List < KeyValuePai < string, object > > > parameters = new Dictionnary<string, List < KeyValuePai < string, object > > >();
}
```

I add data like this in this dictionnary :

```
MyObject.AddParameters("object1", new List < KeyValuePair < string, object > > {
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie1", "value"),
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie2", "value"),
}
MyObject.AddParameters("object2", new List < KeyValuePair < string, object > > {
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie1", "value"),
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie2", "value"),
}
```

Put when i decode my serialized object in php i got :

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "object1": [
      {
        "Key": "propertie1",
        "Value": "value"
      },
      {
        "Key": "propertie2",
        "Value": "value"
      }
    ],
"object2": [
          {
            "Key": "propertie1",
            "Value": "value"
          },
          {
            "Key": "propertie2",
            "Value": "value"
          }
        ]
      },
    }
```

How can i get the correct format from the JSON.Net serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

A better way is to let the JsonConvert.Serialize do his job but insted of set a `List<KeyValuePair>` as parameter i pass an object.

Code is now

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Dictionnary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionnary<string,object>();
}
```

And adding data to paremeters like this

```
MyObject.AddParameters("object1", new {
    propertie1 ="value",
    propertie2 = "value",
});
MyObject.AddParameters("object2", new {
    propertie1 ="value",
    propertie2 = "value",
});
```

Now the serialized Dictionnary as the format expected.

Original answer :

Got it with 21021655 question.

Need to write my own Converter like said in answer

```
class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = value as List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(item.Key);
            writer.WriteValue(item.Value);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // TODO...
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>);
    }
}
```

And return this result `[{"one":1},{"two":2},{"three":3}]`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the data in C# in the form that you want.

The way you add data now, will indeed convert to that output.

You'll need something like this in C#:

```
MyObject.AddParameters("object1", new List < KeyValuePair < string, object > > {
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie1", "value"),
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie2", "value"),
}

MyObject.AddParameters("object2", new List < KeyValuePair < string, object > > {
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie1", "value"),
    new KeyValuePair < String, object >("propertie2", "value"),
}
```

Comment: My example is not revelant, i forget to include the object2 part. But the way that the serialization give me the result not corresponding to the format i looking for.